# Checar valores em txt

Tags: lua

Bom, eu quero salvar um valor em um arquivo txt, checando se ja existe algum valor com 2 coisas iguais.
Ex:

```
local file = io.open("arquivo.txt", "a+")
local oi = {dia=os.date(), numero=math.random(1,10)}
if not () then -- Aqui não sei o que fazer, quero checar se no txt ja tem alguma linha com o valor numero igual a 'oi.numero', se não tiver, salva.
file:write("Data: "..oi.dia.." - Numero:"..oi.numero)
file:close()
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pra começar, [io.open](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-io.open) retorna uma handle para o arquivo (você está jogando ela fora atualmente)

```lua
local fil, err = io.open("arquivo.txt", "a+")
if not fil then error(err) end
```

Depois disso, você pode usar o método [lines](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-file:lines) para percorrer as linhas:

```lua
for line in fil:lines() do
    -- ...
end
```

Para cada linha, você vai precisar fazer um pouco de manipulação de string para ver se a linha contém o número. No seu caso, a maneira mais direta seria usar a função [string.match](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.match), que é um pouco parecida com expressões regulares em outras linguagens de programação.

```lua
local n = string.match(line, "Numero:(%d+)")
if n and tonumber(n) == oi.numero then
   -- achei o número
end
```

---

Se precisar analisar a data você pode fazer algo como

```
local date, n = string.match(line, "Data: (.-) Numero:(%d+)")
if date then
    -- o pattern bateu
    fazAlgoCom(date, n)
else
    -- o pattern não bateu
end
```

O `(.-)` significa "0 ou mais caracteres quaisquer, o mínimo que for necessário".

No entanto, desse ponto pra frente as coisas começam a ficar mais complicadas. Eu preferiria usar uma formato de armazenamento mais estruturado, como CSV, JSON ou um "LuaOn" da vida (tipo JSON, mas com sintaxe Lua). Fica mais robusto (por exemplo, sua versão atual vai quebrar se algum campo tiver uma quebra de linha) e vc pode usar alguma biblioteca pronta para lidar com o trabalho de ler e imprimir as strings no formato certo.

Comment: Explicação perfeita, código perfeito. Obrigado.

Comment: Uma duvida, '(%d+)' seria o que? É uma expressão regular? E como é uma que substitui qualquer valor?

Comment: O `%d+` significa "um ou mais dígitos" e o `()` faz com que essa parte do padrão seja retornada pelo string.match caso o match dê certo. Isso é descrito na sessão do manual sobre [patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1). (Tem uma versão do manual em português se você quiser também)

Comment: Patterns em Lua são parecidos com expressões regulares, mas tem algumas diferenças.

Comment: Mais uma duvida, e no caso do "dia", isso não seria possivel porque tem mais coisa na direita, ou tem como checar até um caractere, como um string.explode?

Comment: Retornar mais de uma coisa não é problema: funções em Lua podem retornar mais de um valor (veja meu edit). Quanto a split/explode não tem na biblioteca padrão, vc precisaria [se virar](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin).

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16629/discussion-between-gabriel-sales-and-hugomg).